# XamDataGrid resize star column

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

How can I resize a `*` column in the `XamDataGrid`? In this example, I cannot resize the `department` column.

---

MWE: `MainWindow.xaml`

```xml
<Window x:Class="GridPerformAutoSize.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:igWPF="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml/wpf"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>

        <igWPF:XamDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">
            <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                <igWPF:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False" />
            </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
            <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                <igWPF:FieldLayout>
                    <igWPF:Field Name="name" />
                    <igWPF:Field Name="department" Width="*" AllowResize="True" />
                    <igWPF:Field Name="salary" />
                    <igWPF:Field Name="email" />
                </igWPF:FieldLayout>
            </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        </igWPF:XamDataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```cs
using System.Linq;

namespace GridPerformAutoSize
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string department { get; set; }
        public string salary { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
    
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.dataGrid.DataSource = Enumerable.Repeat(new Person() { department = "HR", email = "john@hotmail.com", name = "John Smith", salary = "52500" }, 5);
        }
    }
}
```

---

See how no resizing cursor appears between the `department` and `salary` columns:

[image]

---

What do I have to do to be able to resize a `*` column?

How can I have one column use all available space but still allow resizing?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. `Width="*"` as you've seen fills the remaining space depending on other columns width. The other columns are auto, meaning they will adjust to fit their data and then your `department` column will fill that difference amongst the other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `department` field to `Width="*"` prevents it from resizing. To enable resizing of this field it is necessary just remove the width setting in this column.

```xml
<igWPF:XamDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoFit="True">
    <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <igWPF:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False" AutoFitMode="Always" />
    </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
    <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        <igWPF:FieldLayout>
            <igWPF:Field Name="name" />
            <igWPF:Field Name="department" />
            <igWPF:Field Name="salary" />
            <igWPF:Field Name="email" />
        </igWPF:FieldLayout>
    </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
</igWPF:XamDataGrid>
```

You can also try to set `AutoFit="True"` whether the cells and labels will be sized to exactly without the need to scroll.

***Question**: How can I have one column use all available space but still allow resizing?*

***Answer**: You can set `Width="Auto"` for all columns except the one you want to be using all available space but still allow resizing. For this column don't set the `Width` property.*

Comment: That does not seem to help... am I doing something wrong? Now the `department` column can be resized but it does not use all available space

Comment: @Thomas Flinkow: Sorry, I forgot to add `AutoFitMode="Always"`. Usually I'm adding it to the `XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings` automatically. So, try to make two fixes: **1)** add `AutoFitMode="Always"` to the `FieldLayoutSettings`. **2)** Remove `Width="*"`. By the way, for some fields `Width='Auto'` might be added to fit column width to it content, if it's required.